# How can I convert width in percentage to a number value?

Tags: android, view, width, titanium-mobile

I'm creating a view with width = 20%. how can i get an integer value of that.

```
var v = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: '20%',
    left: '10%',
    height: '40%',
    top: '10%'
});
```

I need to convert v.width to digits. How can i do that?

Comment: get the width and height of the screen at runtime, then calculate the percentage based on the that.

Comment: so you are telling me to not use percetage as it is, but to calculate it manualy as 20% is v.width = mainwin.width * 0.20, where mainwin.width = Ti.Platform.DisplayCaps.PlatformWidth?

Comment: yups I meant that. You have the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var screenWidth = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;

var v = Ti.UI.createView({
   width: screenWidth/5 ,
   left: '10%',
   height: '40%',
   top: '10%'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to do that :

```
function turnPercentToDp(percent){

    var dp = 0;

    if(percent){

      if(_.isString(percent) && percent.indexOf('%')>0) {
        percent = parseFloat(percent.slice(0, percent.indexOf('%')))/100;
      }else{
        if(percent > 1){
          percent = parseFloat(percent)/100;
        }
      }

      dp = Math.ceil((OS_IOS ? Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth : (Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth/Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor))*percent);

    }

    return dp;

}
```